# Pixelation of scroll view object, when grayscale mode of the AR camera is turned on

Tags: unity-game-engine, scrollview, shader, augmented-reality, pixel

[image]

Hello everyone!

I have a grayscale shader/ material on the AR camera. The grayscaling works for every object in the scene except for the scroll view object, which can be turn on and off. When the scroll view object is in gray mode, you can see many pixels. The pixels look like they mirror different parts of the scroll view itself. From looking at the image, does someone have an idea why this could happen? Many thanks in advance~

At first, I though it would be 2 shaders that are not compatible (Unity UI Default shader on the scrollview object and a Grayscale shader on the AR camera).

I've tried to just return

```
float4 col = IN.color;

or

float4 col = (1,1,1,1);
```

with a custom simple UI Default shader to check on incompatibilities. But the pixels still appear in grayscale mode.

Update: As it is probably not the shaders fault, it could be the camera. I've found 2 cameras in the project. An AR camera (culling mask: everything except 'UI') and a UI camera (culling mask: 'UI'). When I deactivated the UI camera's camera component, the pixelation does not happen in grayscale mode anymore, but also all UI elements are not shown anymore.

Did not work:

- changing Layer of the scroll view from 'UI' to 'Default'

Worked:

- deactivating the camera component of the UI Camera, but UI elements are not visible anymore...

Answer (score 1):

After trying again another grayscale shader, I've found out that deleting the 'Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha' from the code helped :) although I still don't know why.